# HAML Folder in Views

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, haml

I was wondering if anyone knew how to render a .haml template from a folder within the views folder. My directory setup is:

```
-Views (Folder)
  -Get_Started (Folder)
    -step_1.haml
  -index.haml
```

I would like to render step_1.haml but when i try:

```
haml :get_started/step_1
```

it doesn't work, I get a blank page. Any suggestions? I could have sworn i've seen how to do this somewhere but i cannot remember where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
haml :'get_started/step_1'
```

Comment: I tried that and it thought i was looking for views/views/get_started so i had to change it to haml :'get_started/step_1'. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Please mark the question as an answer so it pops out of unanswered questions. Thanks!